# How many system calls are there in Linux?

Tags: linux

Linux started out with fewer system calls than it has now.

Let say in 2.6.32, how many system calls are there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you look at the source in src/linux2.x/include/asm-generic/unistd.h

__NR_syscalls tells you the number of system calls and also tells you what it is.

Comment: That would be 242 system calls (http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/longterm/linux-2.6.32.y.git;a=blob;f=include/asm-generic/unistd.h;h=d76b66acea952130170b086c7a22ab7e1e167606;hb=HEAD#l627), less than what I expected